# Finding the index of an array consisting of multiple combined subarrays

Tags: java, arrays

This request *doesn't* use a 2D-array. Consider a 1D-array of the following structure where indices are zero-based and lengths are one-based:

Section 0 is an array of a single cell.

Section 1

- Subarray 1

  - index `0`
  - index `1`
  - ...
  - index `n - 1`
- Subarray 2

  - index `0`
  - index `1`
  - ...
  - index `n - 1`
- ...
- Subarray k

  - index `0`
  - index `1`
  - ...
  - index `m - 1`

Section 2 and 3 both have the same structure as Section 1.

There are multiple arrays that are pieced together to mimic a larger one. In total, there will always be four sections: section 0 will always have a single cell, sections 1, 2 and 3 will each have `k` subarray. Subarrays `1` to `k-1` (except the last subarray) will have a length of `n`. The last subarray will have `m` elements and `m < n`.

**The objective:** given an accumulative zero-based index `input`, find the corresponding index that is in a subarray of a section using index formulas, minimal amount of `if` statements and *without* loops.

Here is an example:

- Let `k = 3`, `n = 8` and `m = 5` to all be one-based. Here is the correct output for section 0 and 1:

```
 input =  0 → section = 0, array = 0, subIndex = 0

 input =  1 → section = 1, array = 0, subIndex = 0
 input =  2 → section = 1, array = 0, subIndex = 1
 input =  3 → section = 1, array = 0, subIndex = 2
 input =  4 → section = 1, array = 0, subIndex = 3
 input =  5 → section = 1, array = 0, subIndex = 4
 input =  6 → section = 1, array = 0, subIndex = 5
 input =  7 → section = 1, array = 0, subIndex = 6
 input =  8 → section = 1, array = 0, subIndex = 7
 input =  9 → section = 1, array = 1, subIndex = 0
 input = 10 → section = 1, array = 1, subIndex = 1
 input = 11 → section = 1, array = 1, subIndex = 2
 input = 12 → section = 1, array = 1, subIndex = 3
 input = 13 → section = 1, array = 1, subIndex = 4
 input = 14 → section = 1, array = 1, subIndex = 5
 input = 15 → section = 1, array = 1, subIndex = 6
 input = 16 → section = 1, array = 1, subIndex = 7
 input = 17 → section = 1, array = 2, subIndex = 0
 input = 18 → section = 1, array = 2, subIndex = 1
 input = 19 → section = 1, array = 2, subIndex = 2
 input = 20 → section = 1, array = 2, subIndex = 3
 input = 21 → section = 1, array = 2, subIndex = 4
```

The next entries should be:

```
input = 22 → section = 2, array = 0, subIndex = 0
...
input = 30 → section = 2, array = 1, subIndex = 0
...
input = 38 → section = 2, array = 2, subIndex = 0
...
input = 42 → section = 2, array = 2, subIndex = 4

input = 43 → section = 3, array = 0, subIndex = 0
...
input = 51 → section = 3, array = 1, subIndex = 0
...
input = 59 → section = 3, array = 2, subIndex = 0
...
input = 63 → section = 3, array = 2, subIndex = 4
```

As of now, my formulas with a single `if` statement are able to get the first section only (not section 2 nor 3). The hope is to find a set of formulas to achieve the objective without using `if` statements nor loops. Here is what I have so far:

```
public class Test {

    public Test() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 63; i++) {
            getIndex(i);
        }
    }

    public void getIndex(int i) {
        if (i == 0) {//Aligns output. I couldn't factor it in the formula
            System.out.println("input = " + i + " → " +
                    "section = " + 0 +
                    ", array = " + 0 +
                    ", subIndex = " + 0);
            return;
        }
        int k             = 3;//Number of subarrays for each section
        int n             = 8;//all subarray sizes except last one
        int m             = 5;//last subarray size
        int sectionLength = (k - 1) * n + m;//number of cells in a single
                                            //section (other than section 0).

        //obtaining the values:
        int section  = (i - 1) / sectionLength + 1;//the section (1, 2 or 3)
        int subarray = (i - 1) / (section * n);
        int index    = ((i - 1) % n);
        System.out.println("input = " + i + " → " +
                "section = " + section +
                ", array = " + subarray +
                ", subIndex = " + index);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // all your constants
        final int TOTAL_SECTION = 63;
        final int SUBARRAY_PER_SECTION = 3;
        final int SUBARRAY_SIZE = 8;
        final int FINAL_SUBARRAY_SIZE = 5;

        // keep track of current input number, increase one after each input
        int inputNumber = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_SECTION; i++) {
            
            // if it is 0, all the value is 0, so just print the defualt format with all 0
            if (i == 0) {
                print(inputNumber++, 0 , 0, 0);
                System.out.println();
                continue;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < SUBARRAY_PER_SECTION; j++) {
                
                // if it is last subarray, use the final subarray size
                if (j == SUBARRAY_PER_SECTION - 1) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < FINAL_SUBARRAY_SIZE; k++) {
                        print(inputNumber++, i, j, k);
                    }
                    break;
                }

                // otherwise, just use the normal subarray size
                for (int k = 0; k < SUBARRAY_SIZE; k++) {
                    print(inputNumber++, i, j, k);
                }
            }

            // print a new line after each section done
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    // format of the message, use this method and give the 4 values needed as parameters
    private static void print(int inputNumber, int sectionNumber, int arrayNumber, int subIndex) {
        System.out.printf("input = %2d → section = %d, array = %d, subIndex = %d %n", inputNumber, sectionNumber, arrayNumber, subIndex);
    }
}
```